# No permutation of $S_4$ satisfying the expression.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Q:** Show that there does not exist a permutation $\sigma \in S_4$ satisfying $(1 2)(3 4)\sigma = \sigma(1 2 3 4)$.

I think, there must be an easy way around or do I have to show the results for every permutation of $S_4$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an easy way around.  Hint:  Think about odd and even permutations.

Or another way to do it would be to observe that if such $\sigma$ existed, you would have $\sigma^{-1} (12)(34) \sigma = (1234)$, and perhaps you know something about conjugation and cycle structure that tells you that can't happen.  But the odd and even thing is simpler.

Comment: +1: Always very nice, when somebody comes up with a simpler than expected solution!

Comment: @Jyrki:  Thanks.  I've been teaching this stuff recently, which helps.

Comment: I agree with Jyrki as above. +1

Answer (score 4):

$ (12)(34)  = \sigma^{-1} (1234)\sigma$. You should know that $\sigma^{-1} (1234)\sigma=(\sigma(1)\sigma(2)\sigma(3)\sigma(4))$, so the right hand is cycle of length 4 but the left hand is 2 cycle of  length 2. This is contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Besides to theoretical formal @Tara's approach and by using GAP as follows, you can see that we achieve *nothing* in GAP's environment:

> for alpha in SymmetricGroup(4) do if(alpha^(-1)(1,2)(3,4)alpha=(1,2,3,4)) then Print(alpha,"\n"); fi; od;

Comment: $\ddot \smile \;\;+1\;\;$